# Could use a little explanation of this aspect of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, process

So I've got a Java class that implements Runnable. In the run method I've got the following code and I don't fully understand why it works the way it seems to and was hoping someone could explain it to me.

The code is:

```
public void run() {
    Process p = null;
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    p = builder.command("/opt/program/testscript.sh").start();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;

    try {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        log.info(line);
    }

    boolean running = true;
    while(running) {
        p.waitFor();
        running = false;
    }       

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        p.destroy();
    }
}
```

So, the top part is getting the output from the process that's running and displaying it. The middle part though seems to be where the code waits for the thread to process. As I understand it, the code should stop and wait in the while loop at the `p.waitFor()` command until the thread finishes, and then the whole thing should end. However, output continues to be displayed while the thread is running so obviously the while loop at the top is still being hit.

Threading has always been my weakest point and clearly I'm just not totally grasping what's going on here. The code works though so I guess it's valid. Though perhaps it's not coded the way it should be? Anyway, help is much appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the info all. Makes sense that the while(running) loop doesn't do anything. I will remove it. I added the rest of the code up above that I didn't provide before to give some more context in case anyone has anything further to add.

Comment: Did any of the answers give you the solution/explanation you were looking for, or is there anything else you seek?

Comment: Yeah actually, I guess they did answer the question. Good point, I'll mark one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop stops when who ever is filling `br` closes it.

`p.waitFor()` indeed waits until `p` finishes. The loop is kind of void since it executes exactly once, so you might as well remove it.

Sooo ... assuming `p` is whats filling up br until it is done and exits, the `waitFor` will only have to wait a very short time, possibly not at all.

In order to understand more exactly what is going on one would need the code behind `p`, of whatever fills `br` and how these things get started.

Answer (score 1):

The top loop will run until all input from `br` has been exhausted, then the thread should wait for the process `p` to finish running.

Maybe you see the the continous output, because there is still input in `br`?

Answer (score 1):

`p.waitFor()` is the thread waiting for the process to terminate, it's not waiting "until the thread finishes". If the thread is interrupted (meaning another part of the program with a reference to the thread chose to call `interrupt()` on it, usually because the program is shutting down) before the process that it's waiting for terminates then `p.destroy()` kills the process. The while loop around the waitFor is useless.

You're looking at the code that implements Runnable, but you don't say anything about where the thread is created using that Runnable. Go look for that part, I would expect there are different threads being created using that Runnable.